# Running multiple versions on the same .NET website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-api

I have a website (which is actually mainly a Web API site) and I'd like to be able to simultaneously access multiple versions of it.

What I'm currently doing is creating a new website for each version under IIS and referring to sync2.site.com, sync3.site.com etc.

This solution is not very scale able nor maintainable.

How to quickly add more "versions" of this app and access them using something like `sync.site.com?version=3`?

Answer (score 2):

At my job we do this currently fairly easily just by putting each version under it's own application folder in IIS, so we have URIs like:

```
http://SomeServiceBox/Service/v1.0/
http://SomeServiceBox/Service/v1.1/
http://SomeServiceBox/Service/v2.0/
http://SomeServiceBox/Service/v2.3/
```

Works just fine for us. I can only suggest this until you explain why you wouldn't already be doing such... I'm guessing there's something in the way your service is put together that makes such an approach non-functioning otherwise you would have already done this.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the reply.
As far as I understand - using you're solutions I'll still have to create a website under IIS for each version, am I wrong?

Comment: @Leo no, just one website, multiple applications beneath it. You just right click on the folder where you want the web app to exist (in my example you'd right click the `Service` folder) and select "Create Application", give it the name `v1.0` or whatever, and give it the physical path where the root of the v1.0 app files are, usually the folder that contains a Web.Config and a Bin folder and maybe a global.asax and other files etc